# Get User's emails in AD Group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using this code to get the list of users in a specific group in AD

```
private DirectoryEntry _directoryEntry = null;

private DirectoryEntry SearchRoot
{
    get
    {
        if (_directoryEntry == null)
        {
            _directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapDomain, _user, PBKDF2Algorithm.Decrypt(_password, "PAssword"), AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        }
        return _directoryEntry;
    }
}

public List<User> GetUserFromGroup(String groupName)
{
    List<User> userlist = new List<User>();

    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(SearchRoot)
        {
            Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(SAMAccountName=" + groupName + "))"
        };

        var results = directorySearch.FindOne();

        if (results != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry deGroup = new DirectoryEntry(results.Path, _user, PBKDF2Algorithm.Decrypt(_password, "PAssword"));

            PropertyCollection pColl = deGroup.Properties;
            int count = pColl["member"].Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string respath = results.Path;
                string[] pathnavigate = respath.Split("CN".ToCharArray());
                respath = pathnavigate[0];
                string objpath = pColl["member"][i].ToString();
                string path = respath + objpath;
                DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(path, _user, PBKDF2Algorithm.Decrypt(_password, "!twcActiveDirectory!"));
                User userobj = User.GetUser(user);
                userlist.Add(userobj);
                user.Close();
            }
        }
        return userlist.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.FirstName)).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return userlist;
    }
}
```

The properties returned doesn't contain the email addresses for users, later I found a way to retrieve user's proxyAddress which it's what exactly I'm looking for, but the problem is that I only successfully retrieved the users in the main root, not for a specific group.

Here is the code that retrieves the user's proxyAddress for the root only not for a specific group, as I mentioned before,

```
public List<string> emails()
{
    List<string> userlist = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(SearchRoot)
        {
            Filter = "(&(proxyAddresses=smtp:*))"
        };
        directorySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses");

        var results = directorySearch.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult sr in results)
        {
            foreach (String addr in sr.Properties["proxyAddresses"])
                userlist.Add(addr.Split(':')[1]);
        }
        return userlist;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

so, any way to merge both codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, as follows:

1. load users for each group
2. build login names for each user
3. using PrincipalContext search for each user by their login name
4. load ProxyAddresses and Mail properties for each user

Here is a code that explains the idea:

```
    DirectoryEntry _directoryEntry = null;


private DirectoryEntry SearchRoot
        {
            get
            {
                if (_directoryEntry == null)
                {
                    _directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + textBox5.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                }
                return _directoryEntry;
            }
        }
private void GetUsers(){
  List<string> userlist = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(SearchRoot)
                {
                    Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(SAMAccountName=" + textBox1.Text + "))"
                };


                directorySearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                var results = directorySearch.FindOne();

                if (results != null)
                {


                    DirectoryEntry deGroup = new DirectoryEntry(results.Path, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);

                    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection pColl = deGroup.Properties;
                    int count = pColl["member"].Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        string respath = results.Path;
                        string[] pathnavigate = respath.Split("CN".ToCharArray());
                        respath = pathnavigate[0];
                        string objpath = pColl["member"][i].ToString();
                        string path = respath + objpath;
                        DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(path, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
                        User userobj = User.GetUser(user);
                        userobj.EmailAddress = GetUserEmail(userobj.LoginName);
                        userlist.Add(userobj.EmailAddress);
                        user.Close();
                    }
                }
                //listBox1.DataSource = userlist;
                userlist.ForEach(item => textBox2.Text += item);
                //var t = userlist.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.FirstName)).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace + ex.Source);
            }
}
  public string GetUserEmail(string usr)
        {
            try
            {

                string uid = textBox3.Text;
                string pwd = textBox4.Text;
                string emailProxy = "";
                string emailMail = "";
                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, textBox5.Text, uid, pwd))
                {
                    using (UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context))
                    {
                        user.SamAccountName = usr;

                        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user))
                        {

                            var r = searcher.FindAll();
                            foreach (var result in r)
                            {
                                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                                if (de.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Value != null)
                                {
                                    List<string> tmpAddress = new List<string>();
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (true)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            tmpAddress.Add(de.Properties["proxyAddresses"][i].ToString());
                                            i++;
                                        }
                                        catch { break; }
                                    }
                                    string val = tmpAddress.Where(em => em.Contains("SMTP")).FirstOrDefault();

                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                                        emailProxy = val.Split(':')[1];
                                    else emailProxy = "";
                                }
                                else emailProxy = "";

                                if (de.Properties["mail"].Value != null)
                                    emailMail = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
                                else emailMail = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailProxy) ? emailProxy : (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailMail) ? emailMail : "");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace + ex.Source);
                return "";
            }
        }
```